# Dining philosophers Java

Tags: java, multithreading, dining-philosopher

I got a school assignment today to simulate the dining philosophers problem.

I just made this code to test if it worked this easy way (A).
The problem I am having right now is that when someone that is not supposed to be eating starts to eat anyways. Meaning that when the chopsticks are taken he starts to eat anyways... please give me tips :) here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class OperatingSystem implements Runnable {

    int namn;       // thread name
    int tal;        // the random number
    Random rand = new Random(); // implements random
    boolean chopstick1 = true;
    boolean chopstick2 = true;
    boolean chopstick3 = true;
    boolean chopstick4 = true;
    boolean chopstick5 = true;

    public OperatingSystem(int x){      // constructor
        namn = x;
        tal = rand.nextInt(30000);
    }



    public void think() {       // run method
    try{
        System.out.println(namn + ": " + tal+ " ms");
        Thread.sleep(tal);
        System.out.println(namn + " is done thinking!");

    }catch(Exception e){}

    }
    public void hungry(){

        while(true){
        //  System.out.println(namn);
        if(namn == 1){
                if((chopstick1==true) && (chopstick2==true)){
                    chopstick1 = false;
                    chopstick2 = false;
                    break;
            }


        }
        else if(namn == 2){
                if((chopstick2==true) && (chopstick3==true)){
                    chopstick2 = false;
                    chopstick3 = false;
                    break;
                }   


        }
        else if(namn == 3){
                if((chopstick3==true) && (chopstick4==true)){
                    chopstick3 = false;
                    chopstick4 = false;
                    break;
            }

        }
        else if(namn == 4){
            if((chopstick4==true) && (chopstick5==true)){
                chopstick4 = false;
                chopstick5 = false;
                break;


            }

        }
        else if(namn == 5){
            if((chopstick5==true) && (chopstick1==true)){
                chopstick5 = false;
                chopstick1 = false;
                break;
            }

            }
        }


    }
    public void eat() {     // run method
        try{
            tal = rand.nextInt(30000);
            System.out.println(namn + " is eating");
            Thread.sleep(tal);
            System.out.println(namn + " is done eating!");
        /*  chopstick2 = true;
            chopstick3 = true;
            chopstick4 = true;
            chopstick5 = true;
            chopstick1 = true;
            */
            if(namn == 1){
                    chopstick1 = true;
                    chopstick2 = true;
            }
            else if(namn == 2){
                    chopstick2 = true;
                    chopstick3 = true;

                }


            else if(namn == 3){
                    chopstick3 = true;
                    chopstick4 = true;

                }


            else if(namn == 4){
                    chopstick4 = true;
                    chopstick5 = true;

                }


            else if(namn == 5){
                    chopstick5 = true;
                    chopstick1 = true;

                }


        }catch(Exception e){}

        }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        think();
        hungry();
        eat();
    }



}

///////////////////////////////// here comes the main;


import java.util.*;
public class OperatingSystemMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new OperatingSystem(1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new OperatingSystem(2));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new OperatingSystem(3));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new OperatingSystem(4));
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new OperatingSystem(5));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: I would guess that what youre calling "the easy way" isnt easy at all. You might want to rethink your approach

Answer (score 0):

You have the classic data race problem. Synchronizing it is the key.

For example, if `namn = 3` and it is currently running the line

```
chopstick3 = false;
```

Nothing stops namn = 4 to enter the if, because the condition `((chopstick4==true) && (chopstick5==true))` is true. (Namn 3 didn't yet execute `chopstick4 = false;`)

You must synchronize the acces and the modification to the chopstick variables.